# Throughout all editions, has one been able to cast Feeblemind on oneself and how exactly has it worked?

Tags: spells, dungeons-and-dragons, edition-comparison

Various editions of D&D have had a *Feeblemind* spell. Through each iteration has one been able to cast the spell on oneself and if so is a save required or optional? How has this changed throughout the different editions?

Comment: *Idle Curiosity:* What events made this question important?

Comment: it was a discussion about a potential plot. the idea the person i was discussing this with came up with was that the bad guy would be a disgruntled wizard that got reject from the most prestigious academy in the setting because they claim "he was not smart enough" so he learned on his own and returned for revenge by creating a sort of magic bomb on a timer that would kill anybody with an intelligence above the minimum requirement for a wizard. it could be stopped by a wizard by changing the target to the himself instead of the area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes.

For the following editions of Dungeons & Dragons:

- D&D Expert Rules
- AD&D 1st Edition
- AD&D 2nd Edition
- D&D 3rd Edition
- D&D 3.5 Edition
- D&D 5th Edition

The spell allows a saving throw for each edition. Most editions allow you to willingly fail your saving throw. For others, the rules are silent on whether or not you need to attempt a saving throw against an ally's spell or your own.

This [article](http://deltasdnd.blogspot.com/2017/01/spells-through-ages-feeblemind.html) does an excellent job comparing and contrasting the *feeblemind* spell across editions up to 3rd Edition. The way the spell targets a creature has changed very little across editions. All of them target a single creature and offer no reason why you wouldn't be able to target yourself. Note that the 1st and 2nd Edition *feeblemind* spell can only target magic-using creatures or spellcasters.

As far as I know, 4th Edition does not have a feeblemind arcane power.

Comment: In Expert aren't you still encouraged as a GM to not give saving throws when players do stupid stuff/give saving throws when bad stuff would happen to the PC through no fault of the player?  If so, I'm pretty sure you wouldn't get a save if you straight-up feebleminded yourself.